# Bro Logs address to WSO2 CEP for processing

Tags: logging, complex-event-processing, bro, wso2-cep

I have got a project to perform complex event processing of `bro` logs in order to detect any security lags or attacks and so. I have done initial survey and find out that bro generates various log files and I can make `WSO2 CEP` to take those files and write `Siddhi` queries for event processing. As event receiver of WSO2 CEP takes `xml`, `json` or `text` as message format, have I to change format of bro log files or they can work as it is? As I didn't happen to find any sample of WSO2CEP taking standard log files as event receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately bro support `json` format for log files.
I just modified some default options in `ascii.bro` file like

```
# to use json instead of `tsv` for all log files. It was F bydefault
const use_json = T &redef;
# to display timestamps in a standard format
const json_timestamps:JSON::TimestampFormat = JSON::TS_ISO8601 &redef;
```

And now I am getting all logs in required format.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use CEP file-tail event receiver and then use RegEx to extract the details from the log message, similar to the sample provided [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Sample+0022+-+Receiving+Custom+RegEx+Text+Events+via+File+Tail) (Sample Number 0022 in WSO2CEP 4.1).

Alternatively you can also write a client to extract the log and send it as a `XML` or `JSON` event to CEP in any transport you prefer.